# How to design database system for a feedback systems?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I'm just getting into PHP and MySQL and English is my second language so excuse me while I try to describe my question well.

I'm trying to create a feedback  system where students can leave feedbacks about teachers. A student log in pick a subject first,  then find a teacher who teaches that subject and can leave feedback of that teacher. All the feedbacks of a teacher can be seen by public(no require login) And the teacher can log in have look at the feedbacks and mark them as read,  once a feedback is marked as read it won't be shown publicly again .

The problem I'm having is not about the idea itself or the login system etc,  it's about the database structure.  Mainly the teachers feedback database,  first the teachers are categorised by subjects,  then each individual teacher need to store feedbacks,  and those feedbacks can be active(not read yet) or inactive (read).

Since I'm new to PHP and MySQL I don't know how to design the database to be effective,  let's give a problem as a example "Display the numbers of active feedbacks of a teacher" I can think of few ways to approach this, but can't decide which way is the best.

SOLUTION 1, One massive database to store everything , First it needs to filter the database by the subjects,  then filter by the teacher name/id then filter out the inactive one then count up how many active feedbacks are there

SOLUTION 2, give each an individual database,  and when the student leave feedback it gets stored directly into an active database for that particular teacher ,  when the teacher mark it as inactive it will be moved to a different (inactive) database of that teacher,   so to find out the numbers of active feedbacks just simply count the number of data in that active database.

SOLUTION 3, combine solution 1 and 2, because each teacher can only teach one subject,  so we create big databases for each subject,  and for each subject we create an inactive database where we store inactive feedbacks,  when a feedback is marked as read it will be transferred to that database.  Then to find out numbers of active feedbacks we can filter the subject to find the teacher and just simply count up the numbers of feedbacks that teacher have because all the inactive ones will be at a different database.

I hope I did not confuse you with my description,  I would really appreciate if any of you can tell me the most efficient way to build database for this problem in PHP and MySQL.  Thanks!

Edit 1: sorry I do mean Tables rather than databases, so the question is whether I should create multiple tables for this problem or stick with one.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really the place for questions like yours but unless you're dealing with multiple schools i would go with one database.
Later you could use mysql partitioning if you really needed to.

Comment: Sounds like you might be confusing “database” with “table” … But even if you aren’t: No, a separate table per teacher is not the way to go. The general rule of thumb is: Data of the same structure and meaning goes into one and the same table.

Comment: The general rule of thumb it to read a tutorial on "database normalization" so you understand what a database is and how to design one.

Answer (score 1):

You could first have student table and teacher table. In your feedback table you can have columns: student, teacher, comment, time

Comment: Yes Correct! You should find it a lot easier now

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have multiple tables,for teachers and students and it would be good if use log in functionality too.mainly make sure that design a over all flow of steps,its doesn't be be good choosing subjects and teachers separately,think it in such a way that as soon as you select subject an subject,the appropriate teacher of that particular subject should be also be selected.Better create an clear flow of implementation.